# 'The NODE_ENV environment variable is required but was not specified' issue when setting Cypress component testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cypress

I have an ejected react app for a storybook UI app. I wish to test the components with cypress 11. I've installed Cypress but get this message when going through the set up process.

> The NODE_ENV environment variable is required but was not specified'

Anyone know how to add this properly?